# Log out button for different type of accounts in flutter firebase Auth

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, google-signin

I have a flutter app with multiple sign in options (Email and password, Google account, phone number). Once the user sign in to the application, he will then have a drawer.
There is a Sign out button inside this drawer which should sign the user out when he press it and send him back to the signup page. So I have been using the sign out instance from firebase auth
`await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();`

But since I added the google sign in options I started facing a problem which is that for google sign out, I nee dto disconnect the user first `await googleSignIn.disconnect();`
So I added this line to the sign out function to be like this:

```
  Future<void> SignOut() async {
 await googleSignIn.disconnect();
 await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
 Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (BuildContext context) => AuthPage(),
   ),
       (route) => false,
 );}
```

This button works fine when the user sign in with google but if he signs in with different method then an error will be thrown:

> Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(status, Failed to disconnect., null, null)

How can I handle different type of users signout with one button?

Comment: Check the google signin is empty or not if it is not empty then only signout

Comment: @AmanpreetKaur In this case if the user signs in with phone number for example then google signin will always be empty and he will never be able to signout

Comment: I actually solved it by adding conditions on the signout button. Future<void> SignOut() async {
    if (googleSignIn.currentUser != null){
      await googleSignIn.disconnect();
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();}
    else{
      await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
  }
Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Future<void> SignOut() async {
if (googleSignIn.currentUser != null){
  await googleSignIn.disconnect();
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();}
else{
  await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();}
```